# VS2012 setting file as resource automatically

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012

My project as lots of xaml files that were created by a graphic designer. they are fanccy vector images he made.
My system reads in the file with a streamreader, and uses a XamlReader to read in the contents and display the image on a canvas.

```
string xamlStr;
using (Stream s = Application.GetResourceStream(
                        new Uri(fileUri, UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s))
    {
        xamlStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

Canvas canvas = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(xamlStr);
```

This works great on condition that I remember to make the Build Action on the file a "Resource" and not a "Page"

If I forget my project croaks when trying to read the file.

Is there A way I can make visual studio know that anything inside a specific folder (and it's sub folders) must be treated as a resource